# How to calculate inverse of x-component of a BezierFunction[]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to calculate the inverse of a `BezierFunction[]`'s x-component, defined, for example, by

```
fx[u_] := BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1/8, 3/4}, {1, 1}}][u][[1]]
```

which is the blue curve in the following plot:

[image: fx(u) from BezierFunction]

This curve clearly has a unique inverse for 0 ≤ u ≤1, as shown, for example, by the red dashed lines, which intersect at the coordinate `{0.4,fx[0.4]} == {0.4, 0.22}`.

```
In[1]:=  fx[0.4]
Out[1]:= 0.22

In[2]:=  fx[0.4] == 0.22
Out[2]:= True
```

So I am surprised by the following:

```
In[3]:= FindRoot[fx[u] == 0.22, {u,0.4}]
Out[3]:= {u->0.22}
```

and

```
In[4]:= InverseFunction[fx][0.22]
Out[4]:= 0.22
```

I found nothing in the documentation on the interaction of `InverseFunction` with `BezierFunction`, or `Part`. Anyone know of a way to extract the inverse of the BezierFunction's x-component?

Comment: Oops, I had a typo in the BezierFunction points. Fixed above: the middle point should be {1/8,3/4} to match the plot and the examples given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are being bitten by an old issue that comes up again and again.  You need to restrict the function to numeric arguments, or you are doing a part extraction on an unevaluated expression, yielding merely `u`.

Try this:

```
Clear[fx]

fx[u_?NumericQ] := 
 BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1/8, 3/4}, {1, 1}}][u][[1]]

FindRoot[fx[u] == 0.22, {u, 0.3, 0.5}]
```

```
(* Out[]=  0.4 *)
```

---

Also, `InverseFunction` does not actually find the inverse of a function, but rather is a symbolic representation of the inverse.

Comment: Thank you @Mr. I will commit the ?NumericQ concept to memory.